# ArrayList data getting null when am assigning innner class in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have qualification what is best why to getting data from data base in android. 
my code

```
class MyClass{

List<String> listdata;

public void getData(){

 new DownloadTask (){

     protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
      listdata = result;  
     //  listdata contain 10 records

     }

}.execute();


// here list data is null out side asynctask
  listdata is null

}
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

     protected List<Stirng> doInBackground() {

         return data.getAllRecords();
     }


 }
 }
```

if anything wrong me correct me , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`listdata` is assigned a value in the `onPostExecute()` which is called at a later point  after the `doInBackground()` has finished.

> **`doInBackground(Params...)`** This step is used to perform background
>   computation that can take a long time.
>
> **`onPostExecute(Result)`** invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.

You execute the task and then try to access the value of `listdata` in the next line. It will be `null` as the task has not completed as yet, the `onPostExecute()` has not been called yet.

Answer (score 0):

Its not final. You are not using the enclosed value.

```
class MyClass{

    final List<String> listData;

    public myClass(){
       listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void getData(){

        new DownloadTask (){
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            listData.addAll(result);
            listDataRetrieved();
        };

    }.execute();

   private final void listDataRetrieved(){
       assertTrue(listData != null && containsCorrectElements());
   }

   private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        protected List<String> doInBackground() {
            return data.getAllRecords();
        }
     }
 }
```